# Curriculum framework and model

Tags: meaning, differences, context

What is the difference between *curriculum framework* and *curriculum model*? What I understand is that a *framework* is a set of principles on which a *model* is built. Am I right? Please clarify.

Comment: They are both metaphors, and both too vague to relate consistently. Models tend to emphasize changing or developing (time-related) features, whereas frameworks tend to emphasize hierarchical or structural (space-related) features. In a curriculum context, either would work; use metaphors of change and development with models, and structure and relationship with frameworks. Or the other way around; educational prose is not noted for metaphoric coherence.

Comment: @John Lawler Mixed extended metaphors. If you can't teach, devise curriculum models.// _Keep well._

Comment: Thank you for a very elaborate reply